# Face recognition irrespective of distance from CAM

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am working a video processing project and it demands recognition of the subjects. But I have found that it is unable to recognize accurately when the subject moves away or to the CAM.I am currently using LBP recognizer model witha threshold......I am new to image processing and wil be deligtful if somebdy can suggest some preprocessing techniques tat can enhance the accuracy of facerecognition....

Comment: Are you already resizing the cropped face image to a consistent size? If you have a face detector, you can use that to help choose a tight bounding box -- then you're always running your recognition on a face of the same dimensions.

Comment: I train my recognizer model with 100*100 grayscale detected face images..which are not at all aligned in any way and not at all croped...i do histogram equalization as well...

Comment: So if a face becomes 10x10 pixels the recognizer does not function and you are surprised by this?

Comment: so what dou you thk sir I should do?..I am very new to image processing...i need to resize the training images to lower dimesion?

Comment: @ranger - what do *you* do when the person trying you are trying to recognize becomes too distant?? Hint: sneaker zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the flow specified below..

Raw Image -> OpenCV Face Detector -> Crop the face and resize to a constant size -> Preprocessing like Hist Eq or others -> LBP face recognizer -> Result

All the above steps can be done with OpenCV. Try out different algorithms in each step...

Also why don't you collect during training many images say - ask the user to turn the head from left to right .. up down... front back... This way, you will be covering all the possible variations during the recognition...